# Uv Badly Stretched

Tags: uv, edit-mode, workflow

I am going through my first tutorials using blender and I am having a problem with the UV mapping that is not solved in my tutorial. Hence, I most likely did something wrong during the modelling but I don't know how to fix it yet.

[image]

This is the blade of a sword and as you can see it shows some heavy artifact that I cannot solve.
Already tried *UV > Smart UV Project* but nothing. Could anyone help by any chance?

Comment: Hello, does your object have any modifier ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information on how you unwrapped the mesh. Also check that the scale of the object is applied before unwrapping.

Comment: @Gorgious yes it has subdivision and bevel

Comment: @susu I used only the Smart UV Project, nothing more

Comment: please show how your UV Editor looks like or even share your file (don't forget to pack your images): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Smart UV Project is ok for example if you want to paint your object in the 3D view, but of course if you have a pre-made texture it will probably not match and you need to create seams then Unwrap > Unwrap